# Django: CI/CD, BitBucket Pipelines and VPS

Tags: django, continuous-integration, bitbucket, continuous-deployment, bitbucket-pipelines

Is it possible to have CD set up for BitBucket repo, so that once the code is commited/merged into dev branch, tests are run in BitBucket(or other) cloud, and if tests pass, git pull is triggered on VPS as well as python manage.py commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Bitbucket offers an "integrated CI/CD for Bitbucket Cloud that's trivial to set up, automating your code from test to production." Check it [here](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines)

In addition, if Bitbucket is not a requirement, you can easily use:

```
GitHub -> Travis-CI -> Heroku
```

Try it, if this sounds OK for you.

`UPDATE`: GitHub enabled his own CI recently. It lays under the `Actions` tab. You can publish your Python project on pypi for example.